# What is the difference between using DFWIN or IFWIN module for the Intel's oneAPI Fortran compiler?

Tags: module, fortran, intel, intel-fortran

I compiled an old software, where several "system" modules are used all starting with D (DLIB, DWIN, DWINTY, ...). I noticed that on the [oneline oneApi manual](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/library-modules-and-run-time-library-routines.html) similar modules starting with the "I" instead of the "D" are illustrated. At first sight it doesn't seem to be much different (the software compiles with DWIN or IWIN). Is a D module the debug version of the respective I module?

Comment: I would not be surprised if it were just DEC and Intel... Are you sure they differ at all?

Answer (score 0):

A module in the DF* and MSF* series of names is the same as the corresponding module in the IF* series.  These names series provide for migrations between the compilers from the different corporate entities.

The source code for those compiler provided modules is provided with your compiler installation (e.g. search the installation tree for IFWINTY.f90).  If you inspect the source for the IFWINTY module (just as an example) you will find that it has source for lots of type and constant declarations.  DFWINTY and MSFWINTY, on the other hand, just consist of `USE IFWINTY` (and lots of licence boilerplate).